ASP.NET web site on .NET 4.7.2 - what executable runs?
We have a "web site" project created many years ago. Currently the "web site" project is maintained in VS2019. We use .NET 4.7.2.
The web site resides in our production server, say in the folder d:\mywebsite
Our network team used to have antivirus set to whitelist the entire D: drive. Now they are looking into narrowing down to designated folders.
My question is, which executable runs when the web site runs? I only see a lot of DLLs in the bin subfolder (and a few .exe files, but they don't seem relevant e.g. csc.exe, VBCSCompiler.exe).
Is there another folder (in the C: drive perhaps) that is being executed when a user access the web site and runs a web form? What executable exactly? What is the location?
As a reference, for some desktop Winforms apps, when I compile, an .exe is generated.
Even for web applications I wrote in ASP.NET Core, you can see there is the app executable created.

How is the website being hosted from that server?  Is it a standalone executable?  Is it on an IIS instance?  Something else?  If the whitelist of the entire drive is removed and tested, does the antivirus or server have any logs indicating what failed to run, if anything?

If it runs under IIS then the executable is "w3wp.exe" which is then present as a selected feature of the Window Server installation. I'm a bit rusty if a "Website" project goes through a Build step that produces a DLL for IIS to use or not - perhaps IIS runs it directly from the source files (*.html, *.aspx + *.aspx.cs or who knows even *.asp).

Yes, it runs under IIS. I definitely see w3wp.exe running when there's activity in the website. So I guess this needs to be whitelisted and the bin folder. That's a good start. Thank you

For .NET Framework, which is everything in the 4.x series and earlier, the executable is almost always w3wp.exe, usually in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv, and it runs as part of the IIS web server.
This file is not just your web site. It's a shared host for any .NET code running on that web server, meaning adding this to an allowlist can still be a much broader exemption than desired.
Starting with .NET Core, this is much less likely to remain true, and it's more common for web sites to build as their own separate application. But you can still host .NET Core sites with IIS, and that  remains common in places with shared legacy infrastructure.
Your web site may further load additional *.dll or other binary files, but exactly what that looks like depends on how the project/solution is built. At very least, examine your D:\mywebsite\bin folder and look at the .dll files there.

But if it were me, I would NOT use an allowlist for my site at all. When (not "if", because everyone makes mistakes) we eventually push out a flaw in our code, if someone manages to take advantage in a way that lets them use or mimic malware on my server, I want to know about it as quickly possible. By it's nature, any web site is an attack surface, and to the degree possible I want my attack surfaces monitored.
That is, I believe it's a mistake to blindly trust your own code.
Instead, I like my Test/QA/Staging environments to have the same antivirus protection as production and then ensure everything is well-tested and gets a good work-out before going to production, so I'm confident normal operation does not trigger detections in the first place. If my code is triggering detections, I want to refactor that code until this no longer happens.
There have been times where a 3rd party component would cause detections at load, and we've had to exempt the dll for that library. There have also been times where we've retired the component, and either found a replacement, built the feature ourselves, updated the app to avoid the need, or even done without — because this really is that important.

Thank you for the reply. Yes, we use IIS and it definitely runs w3wp.exe (I had forgotten about that). Also, I will definitely have the whitelist update to be first tested in the test server. My question was more, which things do we need to whitelist? so I know w3wp.exe is one for sure. And from the responses, it seems all the bin subfolder too should be whitelisted? I think this is a good starting place. Thank you very much

@user7221839 Hopefully, nothing will be whitelisted. Let the antivirus software scan your web site!
